# Redirect permanent doesn't works

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have just updated my site from an old asp platform to a new wordpress one. The seo company that is working with Us has inserted a lot of redirects in my htaccess. like this

```
 Redirect permanent     /viewdoc.asp?co_id=2664 https://www.anekitalia.com/cargo/

 Redirect permanent     /blog/evidenza-2/   https://www.anekitalia.com/blog/
```

Problem is that all the redirects of asp links are giving me always 404 page, the other links are working, so this is not related to my vps setup I think, maybe the links like /viewdoc.asp?co_id=2664 needs a different kind of redirect? hope someone can point me to a direction cause this will impact all my SEO activities.
many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `Redirect` directive to redirect URL querystring . You need to use `RewriteRule` .

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^co_id=2664$
RewriteRule ^viewdoc\.asp$ https://www.anekitalia.com/cargo/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your code but is not working, Is there a particular way to place this in my htaccess?

Comment: I placed on top and is working but honestly I don't know how I can rewrite so many urls they are around 400